# Who do Seventh Day Adventist think the Harlot is in Revelation chaps 17 & 19?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, revelation, seventh-day-adventists

According to Seventh Day Adventist’s Who/what is the harlot noted in Revelation?
Why do you or your source think that answer is correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome.  In order to receive a "correct" answer to your question, you'll need to ask for a particular christian viewpoint, for as it currently stands, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Any  opinion backed up with something from the bible no matter what brand name is of interest.   Who is to say whether some person's interpretation of Revelation or the bible is 'correct' when so many experts disagree on so much.  As the OP said cite why you think your opinion or your sources opinion is correct. A citation is very specific and can be verified.

Comment: The traditional Protestant view of the harlot would be disputed by others. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @NigelJ Interestingly enough, ALL Protestant denominations USED to think that the Roman Catholic Church system was the harlot of Revelation. Nowadays, there are few very that do, among those are SDAs and JWs.

Comment: @edwinaoliver, you may want to ask this in Biblical Hermeneutics.

Comment: @jlaverde For reasons that are hopefully obvious or at least understandable, even some Roman Catholics think Rome is the Harlot. Lol.

Comment: @jlaverde JW’s do not believe the harlot is the RCC

Comment: @Nigel  -  Every answer to every question here will be disputed by many others.

Comment: @javerde  -  okay I can try that there but would it be a duplicate post or can I add a tag or what?  I am new here to this site.

Comment: @Kris  -  Okay. do JWs believe it identified anyone or anything or are they as confused as I am at understanding revelation?

Comment: @Kris  -  Well wikipedia seems to think a lot of people, presumably  of some brand name religion believe it.  jlaverde at least provided his reasons.  Can you answer the question?  Prefer citations to support what you say no matter who actually believes it or nor.

Comment: @edwinaoliver if you accept the answer below you should specify in the question that you are looking fir SDA viewpoint. This question is too broad and opinion based as it stands. And the answer below contains misinformation on JWS

Comment: I cannot speak to JWs but at least one person  provided an answer.

Comment: @Kris I'm not too familiar with JW belief. I was going off of what a JW friend told me. I have removed this from the anwer. What else is opinion based in your estimation?

Comment: @jlaverde  my problem with this question is that it isn’t scoped toward a specific denomination so it invites opinions that will not be in agreement. Op accepted your SDA point of view so the question should be edited to ask for SDA view.

Comment: @Kris I believe opinion backed up with Scripture is not a bad thing. It seems like he accepted it as it's the only answer there. Do you wish to answer it from the JW perspective? I think it would be helpful to see all of the perspectives on this matter.

Comment: @jlaverde  ifop wants they can ask for an overview but then each answer would have to provide multiple denominational POV. It is much preferred that op ask separate question for each denomination they want the perspective of. A good start would be to scope this one to SDA since op found your answer helpful. If that doesn’t happen this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: All fallen churches - churches who reject the commandments of God are considered as constituting the harlot of Rev 17. This would include all Protestant churches who have rejected the light from the word after being convicted by the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @OneFace Well. I agree in part. If you look at Revelation 17:5 she has a name on her forehead, "Mystery, Babylon The Great, The Mother Of Harlots And Abominations Of The Earth." The reason why the Roman Church is considered THE harlot in this answer, is because she is the mother, the rest would be considered the daughters, as many followed the non-biblical doctrines of Babylon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Seventh-Day Adventist perspective, and also what many of the reformers believed, the Bible points to the harlot of Revelation as the Roman Catholic system.

1. A woman in prophecy and in Jesus' parables (10 virgins) represents a church or group of believers. (Revelation 12:1-6, 10 virgins, etc.)
2. A harlot represents a church that has been unfaithful to the teachings of God.

> Cause Jerusalem to know her abominations. ... You trusted in your own
>   beauty, played the harlot” (Ezekiel 16:2, 15).

3. She persecuted the saints (Rev 17:6).

4.She was dressed in purple and scarlet (Rev 17:4). The pope often wears the royal color 
of purple at important functions, and red is the color of the robes of Catholic cardinals.

5.The seven heads of the beast (Rev 17:3) upon which the woman is seated are seven mountains (Rev 17:9). It is well-known that Rome, the headquarters of the papacy, is built upon seven hills, or mountains.

6.The beast is guilty of blasphemy (Rev 17:3), a point that also clearly fits the papacy, if you look at the Biblical definition of blasphemy (claims to forgive sins and claims to be God)

7.She ruled “over the kings of the earth” (Rev 17:18). Alexander Flick says that by the 13th century, the pope was “at least in theory ... the ruler of the whole world in temporal and spiritual affairs.” This point could fit no other earthly kingdom or government. The papacy is described in Revelation 17 too clearly for doubt.

This will likely ruffle some feathers and get down-voted around here, but some people still do believe this, among them are SDAs. Also, pretty much all the reformers of old believed this as well. Huss, Wycliffe, Luther, Calvin, Zwingli, Melanchthon, Cranmer, Tyndale, Latimer, Ridley, and many others.

For a in-depth, Biblical study, see [The Other Woman](https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4999/t/the-other-woman).